# How to set a loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create this carousel from scratch and have this for now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
                right: '580px'
                }, 500);                
        }, 3000);

        $('#right').click(function() {
            $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
                right: '580px'
                }, 500);
        });
        $('#left').click(function() {
            $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
                left: '0px'
                }, 500);
        });     
    });
</script>
```

It works when I click "#right" and "#left" but only once. I want to make it work that when I click "#next" again it moves again.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insead of `left: '0px'` use `left: '-=580px'`.
And where you have `right: '580px'` put `left: '+=580px'`. But the user will be able to shift all your li's outside visible areas, you're gonna need some if's.

Comment: The left: '-=580px' does not make it go back it just keeps going forward.

Comment: This made it work thanks. Could you help me out get started with the if's? have no clue on where to start them. Or do I have to re-write the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to think too much, I would suggest something like:
`var n = 1;` (it's in global)
everywhere, where there is `left: +=580px` put
`if (n <= 0)
    return;
n--;` in the beginning of a function. Where there's `left: -=580px` put
`if (n >= 3)
    return;
n++;`
Constant 3 you may change depending on amount of blocks (I took it from the fiddle). And also you can name a counter variable properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the current position of the element using `$('.carousel-inner li').offset()` and add it to the value that you wish to move the element by.